# bootstrap for ember : Change Notification show time

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

How can I change the show time for Notification component in bootstrap-for-ember ?

I have tried following code;

```
{{bs-notifications showtime="1" fadeOutTime="1" fadeinTime="1" style="z-index: 1000; position: fixed; width: 50%; left: 0; right: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 50px;"}}
```

but it does not seems to have any effect. I am raising notification by following code in my Router' action

```
Bootstrap.NM.push('Successfully submitted modal', 'success');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The showtime as well as the fadeInTime and fadeOutTime are calculated in milliseconds.

If you change the notification component's showtime to 4000 it will show for 4 seconds. try this:

```
{{bs-notifications showtime="4000" 
                   fadeOutTime="500" 
                   fadeinTime="200" 
                   style="z-index: 1000; 
                          position: fixed; 
                          width: 50%; 
                          left: 0; 
                          right: 0;                      
                          margin-left: auto; 
                          margin-right: auto; 
                          margin-top: 50px;"}}
```

As you can see I have added time to the fadeInTime and fadeOutTime too.

Check out the docs [here:](http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember/dist/#/show_components/notifications)

Hope this helps.